# TV, mobile video player data usage analytics

Tags: android, ios, iphone, web, tizen

We are Developing a movie applications for all major TVs, mobiles,tabs and set top boxes, which streams movies. We need to track the data usage while playing the movie. Is there any common solution for the same?
Our Streaming devices are 
1. Android Mobile, tabs, TVs
2. Apple iPhone, tabs and Apple TV
3. Samsung Tizen
4. Rokku
5. LG TV
6. Amazon Firestick and FireTV
7. Web